# Case-sensitive Live Search on a Table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Live Search on a Table using jQuery. It works really well but is not case sensitive so `jim` will not show the same as `Jim`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qxks62x9/

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $.map($row.find('td'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text()
}).join(' ');

            
             

      
            if (id.indexOf(value) <0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
}

table th{
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Extension</th></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Carey</td><td>1945</td></tr>
<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Johnson</td><td>1946</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: It **is** case sensitive. Do you want it to be not?

Comment: No, I don't want it to be. I want to be able to enter both `jim` & `Jim` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just lowercase both strings.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maq2xmrv/

- `(id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) < 0)`